# gnuplot ytics notation like Matlab

Tags: gnuplot

I want set the ytics notation like this Matlab figure (with only one x10^-5 on the graphics box) whit gnuplot. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this *by hand* in gnuplot, using the `enhanced` option of many terminals and setting a `label`:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output "out.png"
set tmargin at screen 0.95
set label at graph 0,1.05 left 'x 10^{-5}'
plot x
```

[image]

But note that you'll have to scale the y axis also by hand, for instance by scaling the output of a function `f(x)` to `1e5 * f(x)` in the present case.

If you use the latex terminals then simply use latex syntax for the label: `set label ... '$\times 10^{-5}$'`.

If this is not enough for you, then maybe someone else might come with a more automatic solution.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I'll use this solution for now. I'll wait some day for an automatic solution, after that I'will accept your answer (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @ddg Sure, no problem, I'm also interested in knowing if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A more automated solution is to use the `unknown` terminal to estimate the autoscaled yrange limits, calculate the order of magnitude, set the scale and replot:

```
set terminal push
set terminal unknown
scale = 1.0
plot 'data.dat' using 1:($2/scale) w lp
set terminal pop

max(x,y) = (x > y ? x : y)
exponent = log10(max(abs(GPVAL_Y_MAX), abs(GPVAL_Y_MIN)))
oom = (ceil(exponent) == exponent ? exponent : ceil(exponent) - 1)
scale = 10**oom
set encoding utf8
set label left at graph 0, graph 1.05 sprintf('✕ 10^{%d}', int(oom)) enhanced

set tmargin 4
replot
```