# gnuplot how to set tics format by power of 10

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot with:

```
xtics = {0, 2000, 4000, ..., 20000}
```

and I would like them to be shown as:

```
0 2 4 ... 20
      x 10^3
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: See also [gnuplot ytics notation like Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28373020/2604213) for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by setting a label at the appropriate position:

```
set label 1 "× 10³" right at graph 1, -0.05
```

This would place the text *× 10³* right aligned with the right border of your plot and somewhat below it. You probably have to adjust the vertical position (−0.05) a bit depending on your plot.

However, I recommend against indicating factors like that and suggest to incorporate them in the axis label and use `set xlabel "amount [10³ potatoes]"` for example. The kind of labels you want to use are easy to miss and fortunately not common anymore.